# #[ink(constructor)] cause a error, What is wrong with it?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, rust, astar

```
error: encountered unexpected ink! attribute
  --> lib.rs:80:15
   |
80 |         #[ink(constructor)]
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

when I execute `$cargo +nightly contract test` , the above error is happened.

The code is based on the following article.
https://learn.figment.io/tutorials/build-polkadot-amm-using-ink#creating-a-frontend-in-react

Here is the code for the part pointed out.

```
    #[ink(constructor)]
    pub fn new(_fees: Balance) -> Self {
        // Sets fees to zero if not in valid range
        Self {
            fees: if _fees >= 1000 { 0 } else { _fees },
            ..Default::default()
        }
    }
```

Comment: With what version of ink! are you trying to build this example? Can you push your full repo to some GitHub account so that I can give it a try building it?  In the most recent version of ink! you should probably replace the `HashMap` storage type by `ink_storage::Mapping` which also requires an initialization in the constructor: https://use.ink/datastructures/mapping/

Comment: @Achim 
the same error was happened when I changed as you said....
Repo:https://github.com/tnkshuuhei/WasmAMM/tree/master/amm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did check out your repo: you need to move the constructor as well as all message's and other parts of the Smart Contract logic within the actual implementation `impl Amm { /* code here */ }`

I did a PR to your repo which fixes this part:https://github.com/tnkshuuhei/WasmAMM/pull/1. The code will still not compile, as I've already mentioned in my comment you need to replace the `HashMap` with the `Mapping` struct to get it working with an up to date version of ink!. See: https://use.ink/datastructures/mapping/ for details.

Comment: I appreciate your help!! also your comment on PR and above are helpful for me.
the error wasn't happened but new errors come to me haha
I will try Mapping struct. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! If this answers your original question, feel free to mark it as a solution. You are also welcome to ask more questions regarding your implementation.

Comment: Im very happy to meet a kind man as you in my first question!! I like the people at Parity more now haha.