# I got this error when I converted HashMap to Mapping

Tags: ink, rust

As you can see [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/inkconstructor-cause-a-error-what-is-wrong-with-it/5244?noredirect=1#comment5007_5244), I have changed `HashMap` to `Mapping`.

Then I got a lot of errors like this, does it mean that there is no `entry` in Mapping?
version is bellow `ink_storage = { version = "3.3", default-features = false }`

```
error[E0599]: no method named `entry` found for struct `Mapping` in the current scope
```

`method not found in Mapping<ink_env::AccountId, u128>`
[image]

======================

This is within the Withdraw function in AMM.
In my case, the bellow code is before I change.

Token1balance = Mapping,Amount of Token1 each user have

amountToken1,2 = withdrawal amount of Token1,2 from pool

```
        self.token1Balance 
            .entry(caller)
            .and_modify(|val| *val += amountToken1);
        self.token2Balance
            .entry(caller)
            .and_modify(|val| *val += amountToken2);
        Ok((amountToken1, amountToken2))
```

Does the above code update the `token1Balance`, which is the amount of tokens held by each user, and add the `amoutToken1` that was `withdrawn` from the pool?

Answer (score 2):

Correct, you need to read the state variable with `.get`, modify it and then write the updated result back to contract state with `.insert`.

Check the details [here](https://docs.rs/ink_storage/3.3.1/ink_storage/struct.Mapping.html)

So updating an entry from a `mapping` between a `key` and a struct would roughly look like:

```rust
let old_balance1 = self.token1Balance.get(&caller).unwrap();
self.token1Balance.insert(&caller, &(old_balance1 + amountToken1));
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
How would I describe if I want to update a mapping by adding a specific value to a value that is already in the mapping?

Comment: Updated my answer above with an example.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I don't think I understand it properly. I have updated my question as well.

Comment: I was assuming you mapping's value is a struct. In the referenced case its simpler, I updated my example above. Read the mapping's value to get the old value and then write the new one which depend's on the old value.